# Signed division not working in z3py

Tags: z3, z3py

I was trying to work with z3py. I came across a strange problem. I read that the operation `/` is treated as signed division for bit vectors in z3py. I was trying to give the following commands:

> a = z3.BitVec('a',2)
>
> b = z3.BitVec('b',2)
>
> solver = z3.Solver()
>
> solver.add((a + b)/2 == 3)
>
> solver.check()

The result z3 gives is `unsat`

In my views this is not correct because it has a solution `a = 2, b = 0`, `a = 2` in 2's complement means `a = -2`, so `(a+b)/2` must be equal to `-1` i.e. `3` by signed representation.

Can anyone please help me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution myself!

The problem is in expression `(a+b)/2`. Here `a` and `b` are Bit Vectors of size 2. So the denominator `2` of the expression is also treated as a 2-bit Bit Vector by z3. So the `2` in denominator is actually `-2`. Thus the constraint I was trying to solve was `(a+b)/(-2) == -1` This is actually `unsat`.